# django template access url kwargs

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to access kwargs with their names in url from "django template tags".
for example i have a url as below:

```
path('sample_view/<slug:my_custom_slug>/', views.sample_view.as_view(), name='sample_view')
```

what should I write in my html template to access "my_custom_slug"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
{{request.resolver_match.kwargs.my_custom_slug}}
```